# Using Master Theorem when there are more than 1 elements in the f(n)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recurrence-relations, asymptotics

I'm trying to figure out how you would apply the Master Theorem to these two cases:
$$
\begin{split}
T(n) &= 2 T(n/2) + n \log(n) + 3n\\
T(n) &= 2 T(n/2) + n (\log(n))^2
\end{split}
$$

I have some sort of idea for the first one, since you could say that $f(n) = n \log(n) + 3n$ and then since $n\log(n)$ grows fastest, the rest of it can be dropped which gives $T(n) = 2 T(n/2) + n\log(n)$ but I've no idea on how to approach the second one at all. I know how to apply the Master Theorem, I'm just not sure how to apply it to these cases since they're not in the usual form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Putting this into the form $T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)$, we have $a=b=2$ and $f(n) = n \ln^2(n)$, so $c = \log_b a = \log_2 2 = 1$, and 
$$
f(n) = n \ln^2(n) = \Theta\left(n^c \ln^{1+1}n\right),
$$
This means you are in the second case of the [Master Theorem in Wikipedia formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)), for $k=1$. Can you now complete the problem?

**UPDATE**

The conclusion of the master theorem is that 
$$
T(n) = \Theta \left(n^c \log^{k+1} n\right),
$$
but we already saw that $c=1$ and $k=1$, from the formulation above. Can you plug in?

Comment: Wouldn't this be the second case since $c = log_ba$ , as $log_ba = 1$ and $f(n) = (n log(n))^2$ so $c = 1$ due to $n^c$ ?

Comment: @xKetjow of course, typo, will change in a sec

Comment: Ok so I'm not sure if this is right but I got $Θ(n(log(n)^2)^2$ since $k=1$ and the second case will cause $k$ to become $k = k + 1$ so $2$ ?

Comment: @xKetjow close but not quite. Please see the update

Comment: $Θ(n(log^2n)^2$ I think, unsure what happens to the $^2$ on the outside. The way I was taught the notation for case 2 is $T(n) = Θ(n^c(log n)^{k+1})$ which seems to be slightly different than that one.

Comment: @xKetjow $(\log (n))^a = \log^a (n)$, a common notation. so the result should not have the outside $2$...

Comment: Ah ok, so if the $f(n)$ is transferred to $f(n) = Θ(n(log^2n)$ due to that notation, doesn't that now mean that $k=2$ so the final answer is $Θ(n(log^3n)$ ?

Comment: @xKetjow $f(n) = n\log^2(n) = n^c \ln^{k+1}(n)$, so $c=1$ and $k=1$.

Comment: Ah I see now, ok thank you!